# Add button widget in Bokeh to shift my graph left & right

Tags: python, bokeh

[image]
[image]

I am new to Bokeh.  I have modified the CandleStick example from the gallery. The first image with a dozen charts, is ultimately what I'm looking to create.. but let's ignore this for now, look at the simpler second image.

I modified example code and added a hover function + used 4 points of my own data.

I am doing some backtesting, I want to have a forward '->' & backward arrow '<-' widget,  where I click on and it moves the chart forward or backward by 1 day..

I find there is mention on widgets on website, but I cannot find a button widget that I can use to scroll left and right interactively.  There are slider variations but this is not what I want ideally.

It should be simple but I can't find anything in the gallery, or cant find online.

1) Does anyone know a button type widget I can add that would allow me to interactively click on it and scroll my chart?

2) Ultimately I want to have approx 20 charts together, eg for Gold, Crude Oil, S&P500 index.. all with the same date range, and when I click the forward or backward button, all charts shift left or right for the same date.

I'd ideally like to click on a chart and have a master big chart at the top, that, whatever small chart I am in, will update the big chart. I.e. I can hover on any of the smaller charts, eg Gold or Crude Oil, and a big chart at top will also show a bigger version of the products Im currently looking at. Is this possible in Bokeh with standard code? Or will I have to get involved with the bokeh server? [Do you think Bokeh is the right tool for me or should I be using something else?]

Any help greatly appreciated! Thank-you very much

```
from math import pi

import pandas as pd


# Create 4 data points..  (my real code will have 1000's of data points)
x= [
    {'date':'2015-01-01', 'open':100, 'high':110, 'low':97, 'close':106},
    {'date':'2015-01-02', 'open':103, 'high':108, 'low':95, 'close':99},
    {'date':'2015-01-03', 'open':104, 'high':115, 'low':92, 'close':106},
    {'date':'2015-01-04', 'open':106, 'high':107, 'low':76, 'close':78}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

mids = (df.open + df.close)/2
spans = abs(df.close-df.open)

inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms

output_file("candlestick.html", title="candlestick.py example")

high=df.high
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(open=df['open'],high=high,low=df.low,close=df.close))
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(open=df['open'],high=high,low=df.low,close=df.close))

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save, hover"


p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, plot_width=1000)

p.segment(df.date, df.high, df.date, df.low, color="black", toolbar_location="left")#,source=source)
p.rect(df.date[inc], mids[inc], w, spans[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black", source=source)
p.rect(df.date[dec], mids[dec], w, spans[dec], fill_color="#F2282E", line_color="black",source=source2)

p.title = "MSFT Candlestick"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3

hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))

hover.tooltips = [
    # add to this
    ("index", "$index"),
    ("high", "@high"), 
    ("low","@low"),
    ("close","@close")
]


show(p)  # open a browse
```

Comment: Hey guys, I haven't yet had a reply from this. I'm not sure if it's because  i) people just don't know the answer    ii) it's considered such a stupid question it ain't worth the time to reply!    any help would be greatly apprecaited. Thanks guys

Comment: Hi guys,  I didnt hear back from anyone. I tried looking lodes on the Bokeh tutorials/example pages , but alas.. there is a mention of custom widgets but no mention of buttons. I figure Bokeh is dying out and probably not that useful given it can't easily do simple stuff like this. Just incase anyone else is having the same issue, I've decided to switch to PyQt4 and I'm using pyqtgraph, I've found out how to make candles in here and its very easy to add buttons and anything you need.

Comment: Bokeh had 130,000 conda+pip installs in November 2016, and just hit 5200 stars on GitHub. It is in no way dying out. Sometimes questions get overlooked on SO, for no particular reason. That's regrettable, but not a no excuse to spread FUD.

Comment: To add more, there are several examples with buttons hosted at https://demo.bokehplots.com/ with source code. If you want a button to have a callback that changes the range of a plot that is trivial to do in two lines of code.

Comment: @user3087320 Did you find the solution to your question? I'm looking to do something very similar...

Comment: @bigreddot If it is so trivial and easy for you why don't you post an answer to that question? I am looking into a similar problem at the moment, I have been looking at the example page you pointed at and there is no similar use case on it...

Comment: If you want a callback to change a range then the callback literally just needs to change the range, e.g. `plot.x_range.start = 10`